# Dice program, need to either eliminate array or allow for dynamic array size

Tags: c++

I'm almost done with a dice rolling program and my only issue is that I'm unable to input more than 5000 rolls, due to the size of the array I've specified. While I suppose I could simply increase the size of the array to some ridiculous number, I'd prefer not to and instead use a dynamically sized array based on the input `remainingRolls.` Can anyone help?

NOTE: This is the edited and final code that works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int roller(){ // loop to simulate dice roll 
    int die1, die2;
    int total;
    die1 = rand()%6+1;
    die2 = rand()%6+1;
    total=die1+die2;
    return total;
}

int main(){
    int numberOfRolls;
    int remainingRolls;
    int eights=0; // declare counter array to hold frequencies of dice results
    int i;
    int value;
    float percentage;
    int currentRoll; // declare array for dice values

    currentRoll= 0;
    cout << "How many times will the dice be rolled?" << endl;
    cin >> remainingRolls;// user input # of dice rolls
    numberOfRolls = remainingRolls;// variable to hold number of rolls (for output)
    for (i=0; remainingRolls >0; remainingRolls--){// loop to count frequency of each value
        currentRoll = roller();// activate diceRoll function
        if (currentRoll == 8){
        eights++;
        }   
    }   
    percentage = (eights*100/numberOfRolls);
    cout << "The dice were rolled " << numberOfRolls << " times." << endl;
    cout << "The value 8 came up " << eights << " times or " << percentage << "% of the time." << endl;

    getch();
    return 0;   

}
```

Comment: You should say that you've edited the code after you posted it. Otherwise things will be harder for others who wants to learn from this.

Comment: Will do. I'll edit the first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply eliminate the array. You never access the values in the array outside of the loop, so you can replace it with a local variable.

Create a variable `int currentRoll` at the start and replace all occurances of `diceValues[i]` with currentRoll.

Comment: That's what I was hoping I could do. However, what do I do about this line: `for (i=0; i < 4999; i++)`? It seems like that `i < 4999` would throw something off. What can I change that `4999` to, or do I even need to?

Comment: @BrianTucker That for loop is not needed. You don't even read the 0s you set with it. The next line involving the array is `diceValues[i] = roller();` which just overwrites the 0 anyways.

Comment: @BrianTucker Ironically, it should be `i< 5000`(or `i <= 4999`) to set every value in the array. But it does not matter anyways.

Comment: I've now changed the original code to the edited code and it all works fine. Is there a way for me to delete the second for loop?

Comment: Didn't think so. Thanks for the help two nights in a row!

Answer (score 4):

Use a vector and let it grow to the size you need.  Just `push_back()` the new rolls.

Comment: I've never used vectors but just took a look at the cplusplus.com page for vector::push_back and I'm afraid I'm just as confused as ever. Would you mind guiding me through what you mean?

Comment: @BrianTucker, vectors are dynamic arrays that manage the memory for you. `vector<int> v;` - empty. `v.push_back (1);` - {1}. `v.push_back (5);` - {1, 5}.